# button.performclick(); not working in form1 minimized state c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a code that auto clicks on a button after certain time so i put only

```
button1.performclick();
```

its working but when form1 is in minimize state , its not working

i put the following code but its not working

```
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
```

Help wanted !

Comment: How often do you need it to click the button?

Comment: there is  a timer so after time finishes the button should be clicked auto

Comment: So it only click one time only then stops clicking or is it going to keep clicking on a certain interval?

Comment: A user will set a timer manually,so it will click only one time as its a button which stops the process and is only clicked after time finishes . It will get clicked again if user reset timer

Comment: You do not need to "click the button", it seems. What you need is to execute the code behind the button handler. So instead of calling `.PerformClick` why don;t you just call the handler of the button itself?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a similar situation in VB where PerformClick wasn't working if the form is minimized was I created a function and pasted all the button click code in that function. Then I simply call the function from the button click's code instead of using PerformClick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather create a void than a click event, and i'd  call it from the click event too

like this

```
public void clickedbutton1()
{
    //your code for buttonclick
}
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
{
    clickedbutton1();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
else
}
    clickedbutton1();
}
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clickedbutton1();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best I can think of is doing something like this.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: its same ,i did try this same but not working in minimized state.

Comment: I got it ,i should put     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;     first then    button1.PerformClick();    so as form gets in normal state and button gets clicked

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding you. Try `Application.DoEvents();` in form load